# SQL Server 2008 dbms and Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gridview

I need to add one more column in gridview as difference of `Supplier_Quantity - Store_quantity` and that difference should be stored in new column after the `supplier_Quantity`.

But, when I click on `Calculate` button column what should I do then ?

I tried the following query:

```
select 
    Product_Name, Supplier_Quantity, Store_Quantity,
    'DIFFRENCE' = Supplier_Quantity - Store_Quantity 
from 
    relatesupp
```

but it shows in sql only and as soon as I use it in Visual Studio it doesn't show in gridview.

Comment: Yes it works in sql but in visual studio it gets nothing .. i need same result that shown in sql

Comment: kk vaibhav let me try then in datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the code in the button and get the desired result in the datagridview :

```
string sQuery = "select     Product_Name, Supplier_Quantity, Store_Quantity, Supplier_Quantity - Store_Quantity As 'DIFFRENCE' "
 +"from     relatesupp";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con); 
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();          
dt.Load(sdr);
dataGridView1 .DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: ok i marked as answer  for both of them... thank you once again